# What does "$ℝ^{4\times10}$" mean

Tags: notation

I was given this statement:

> where $W\in\mathbb R^{4\times 10}$ and $\vec{b}\in\mathbb R^4$.

Now, I understand that $ℝ^{4}$ means that the set of real numbers in four dimensions. However, I am not sure what $ℝ^{4\times10}$ mean?

Comment: Usually matrices of dimensions $4$ by $10$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The notation

$$ \mathbb{R}^{m \times n} $$

is sometimes used to refer to the vector space of two-dimensional arrays of real numbers consisting of $m$ rows and $n$ columns.

It is rather common to identify this with the space of $m \times n$ real-valued matrices.

There is a nice coincidence of notation, since as abstract vector spaces there is an isomorphism

$$ \mathbb{R}^{m \times n} \cong \mathbb{R}^{mn} $$

obtained by rearranging the entries into a one-dimensional array.

Comment: Regarding the second sentence, do you not define an $m \times n$ real-valued matrix to be a two dimensional array of real numbers consisting of $m$ rows and $n$ columns?

Comment: Was the distinction between two dimensional array and matrix really necessary/helpful?

Comment: I didn't mean for that to come of snarky, sorry. It's an actual question, lol

Comment: @littleO: I consider the term "matrix" to imply a context with additional algebraic structure, namely matrix multiplication.